# AWS s3 : How to list certain objects fast

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to explore if i can list certain objects in less than a second in s3. I have about 200,000 photos in a bucket, some of the photos are related to others: e.g. 6003-01.jpg is related to 6003-02.jpg. I am using this code to extract:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'images'
prefix = 'Photo/'
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
file_names = []
for response in response_iterator:
    for object_data in response['Contents']:
        key = object_data['Key']
        if key.startswith('Photo/6003-'):
            file_names.append(key)
print(file_names)
```

This code does work but it's far too slow. I know the usual method is to use a DB   but I want to see if I can avoid that cost.

Do you know of a quicker way?

Is it possible to make another bucket using this one by script that puts these matched images (6003-) into its own 'directory' and then return all those objects - that would be faster as it would search through a smaller prefix?

Thanks.

Comment: as an update the awscli command " aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket images --max-items 20 --prefix Photo/6003-  --output json " works a lot faster (at an acceptable speed) although is unsuitable as I wouldn't be able to use it inside a lambda function with a dynamic prefix.

Comment: If that awscli invocation works for you then you should be able to write the equivalent in a Lambda function using an AWS SDK. The awscli, after all, is simply a boto3 client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html).

It can provide a daily listing of all the objects in an Amazon S3 bucket in CSV format.

**Benefit:** No need to list the objects yourself

**Disadvantage:** It is only provided once per day

Another method of tracking objects is to have Amazon S3 trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever objects are added/deleted. The Lambda function then stores the object information in a database (eg DynamoDB). Then, you query the database rather than S3.